# Inserting CSS ID in wordpress editor in Visual Mode - May be a short code, but don't have a logical clarity

Tags: css, wordpress, shortcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvX4l.jpg)

In the text mode of the WordPress Code editor we can insert ID's, but how can we do this in the Visual Mode?

I can create a shortcode, but I am an unable to have a clear logic to implement the idea. Please Help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzkzD.jpg)

Comment: Other than a shortcode you can't. Visual mode is intended to act like a simple wysiwyg word processor. This is one of the reasons text mode and the source code edit button in TinyMCE exist.

Comment: Can u give me a clue so that I should start building a shortcode? Shortcode will be build in way so that it can insert an HTML arrangement I guess.

Comment: With WP 5.0 scheduled to come out soon you may want to consider creating a custom block for Gutenberg instead. Shortcodes will be available but they're the old-fashioned way.